# Mosby MVP - how to recreate Fragment's state after onDestroyView()?

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvp, mosby, android-mvp

I'm using [Mosby](https://github.com/sockeqwe/mosby) Model-View-Presenter library in an Android app. In one particular view I'm using [Bottom Navigation](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html) implemented with [Design Support Library v25.1.0](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html). I'm switching between 3 fragments in an Activity. For handling rotation configuration change I'm using Mosby's custom [RestorableViewState](http://hannesdorfmann.com/mosby/viewstate/).

The problem I have is that Mosby is storing View's state in Activity's onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) which is NOT called when I swap fragments in the same activity, only Fragment's onDestroyView() is being called. Currently I'm storing the state separately in the Fragment itself (since the fragment is not destroyed during switching fragments, just the Fragment's view) but I have redundant code which kinda defeats the purpose of using MVP architecture.

Is there any more elegant solution to store Fragment's state during both orientation change AND swapping fragments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little bit tricky. I guess you are making a FragmentTransaction with `replace()` aren't you? The problem is that with replace you are really creating a new Fragment instance every time. Hence no state that can be restored. You should rather call `FragmentTransaction.show(fragment)` and `FragmentTransaction.hide(fragment)`.

Also Mosby 2 doesn't have prefect support for this usecase, Mosby 3 will have better support for that.

Comment: Thank you Hannes for clearing that one out! Yes, I'm using replace right now, have also implementation with hiding/showing fragments but from what I've read it might not be the best way for implementing this kind of UI pattern (up to five views which might get memory heavy). Looking forward to us Mosby 3!

Comment: Well Mosby3 can't solve that problem either. Whenever you call `replace()` the previous Fragment will be destroyed and a newly instanciated Fragment will be added. No library / framework can solve this problem because you are really creating a new object (fragment) with a completely new state and presenter

Comment: To be 100% clear, I used this library: https://github.com/ncapdevi/FragNav/blob/master/frag-nav/src/main/java/com/ncapdevi/fragnav/FragNavController.java - switchTab method. It is not destroying Fragment, only onDestroyView() is called.

Comment: Oh, I will take a look into that library at the end of this month. Perhaps that with this library some extra steps (or extra MosbyDelegate) is required since the default MosbyDelegate is taylored for FragmentManager but FragNav is doing some extra stuff on top of it... I will take a look ...